# New way to synchronize preferences for firefox add-on?

Tags: synchronization, firefox-addon

I maintain a Firefox add-on which stores some settings in a preference `extensions.myextension.mypref`. In order to synchronize this preference between multiple Firefox profiles, I used to simply set the pref `services.sync.prefs.sync.extensions.myextension.mypref` to true. This used to work fine until at least half a year ago. But recently, I noticed that this does not seem to work any more. Searching for a solution I found that [the article that describes syncing of preferences](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Archive/Mozilla/Firefox_Sync/Syncing_custom_preferences) has been moved to the "archive of obsolete content" at MDN.

Is this method for syncing custom preferences of Firefox add-ons no longer supported? And is there any alternative way?

Comment: Excellent question! Im not sure how to do this using the sync software, but to sync across profiles on a local machine i save my prefs to my own ini file on hd.